# How to change wall paper by using powershell

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how to change wall paper by using powershell without logoff?

I want to see the changes right away after I run script.

I can change registry

```
set-ItemProperty -path $reg_pic -Name wallpaper -Value path_to_pic
```

but i need to log off and login again. then i found if i run

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True
```

it will make changes without logoff, but after couple times testing, it wont work anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can help:

I tested it with BMP and JPG files and no logoff/logon was necessary.

[Source MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @" 
using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Params
{ 
    [DllImport("User32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
    public static extern int SystemParametersInfo (Int32 uAction, 
                                                   Int32 uParam, 
                                                   String lpvParam, 
                                                   Int32 fuWinIni);
}
"@ 

$SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014
$UpdateIniFile = 0x01
$SendChangeEvent = 0x02

$fWinIni = $UpdateIniFile -bor $SendChangeEvent 

$path = "C:\TEMP\MyImage.bmp"

$ret = [Params]::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, $path, $fWinIni)
```

Comment: WOW !!! This is great help, it works perfectly on my test PC, I have to try on production PCs where have GPOs applied for clocking up wall paper. the only concern for running PS script is that i have to change excutionpolicy. Thank you for help.