# "Apply" changes to the registry to change mouse settings without reboot on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

### Objective

I am attempting to change the cursor schema with a powershell script **avoiding reboots or log outs**.

That is basically a big resume but, to have a context, I am learning about Windows OS and the PowerShell language... yes, that means that I have low knowledge about this OS (I am more comfortable in Linux :')).
To learn this language I decided to make a script which change some OS settings and is the time for the cursor schema.
I attempted to change the language (UI and internal), and also needs a reboot (I guess it's almost the same).

### Actual Code

I have this function after lots of modifications:

```
function changeMouseScheme {
        function updateRegistry {

            $imagePath = "C:\Windows\Media\Resources\Images\newCursor.jpg"

            $regConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]"CurrentUser","$env:COMPUTERNAME")
            $regCursors = $regConnect.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Cursors",$true)

            $regCursors.SetValue("","Windows Black")
            $regCursors.SetValue("AppStarting", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("Arrow", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("Crosshair", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("Hand", "")
            $regCursors.SetValue("Help", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("IBeam", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("No", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("NWPen", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("SizeAll", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("SizeNESW",$imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("SizeNS", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("SizeNWSE", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("SizeWE", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("UpArrow", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.SetValue("Wait", $imagePath)
            $regCursors.Close()
            $regConnect.Close()

            Write-Output "[+] Mouse registry updated"
        }
        
        function applyChanges {
            $code = @'
                [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
                public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo( uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
                
                public static void applyRegistry() {
                    SystemParametersInfo(0x0057, 0, "", 0x01 | 0x02);
                }
'@
            Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name applyMouseRegistry -Namespace User32
            [User32.applyMouseRegistry]::applyRegistry()

            Write-Output "[+] Mouse registry applied"
        }

        updateRegistry
        applyChanges

        Write-Output "[+] Mouse scheme changed"
    }
```

But when executing it, the cursor does not change.

### Observed resources (no one worked)

I did a deep search on these pages but nothing worked:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/
https://superuser.com/questions/1769195/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-using-powershell-script-on-windows-11-without-restart
[How to change wall paper by using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180893/how-to-change-wall-paper-by-using-powershell)
[Change and update the size of the cursor in Windows 10 via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104778/change-and-update-the-size-of-the-cursor-in-windows-10-via-powershell)

### Expected result

When the script is executed, the cursor schema changes **without** some kind of reboot / log out / shutdown, etc, etc...

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that it's likely failing because the image is a .jpg and not a .cur file.  Try converting the .jpg to a .cur and see if that works for you.

Comment: @Seb It was something so simple..., your comment was true, the image was a jpg and not a cur ... Thank you for your help!